# Find number of udp and tcp packets in .pcap file with scapy

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

Hello everyone I am trying to find some way to check out how many tcp and udp packets I have when I sniff .pcap file with scapy. I would be happy if you could explain to me some way to do this.

```
from scapy.all import *
import time

def main():

path = raw_input("Enter path: ") # .pcap file
packs = rdpcap(path)
option = 0
while (option != 4):

    print "Options: soon "
    option = input("Enter your option: ")
    i = 0
    count = 0
    if(option == 1):
        print "Number of packets: "
        pack_len = len(packs)
        print pack_len
        print "Sniff tome: "
        print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(packs[0].time))
        print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",   time.gmtime(packs[pack_len-1].time))

    elif(option == 2):
        pass # HERE I NEED TO CHECK HOW MANY TCP AND UDP PACKETS I HAVE

    elif(option == 3):
        path = raw_input("Enter new path: ")
        packs = rdpcap(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'in' command, for example (sorry about the messy code, it's late here):

```
for i in range(0, len(packs))
          pkt = packs[1]
          if (TCP in pkt):
                   countTCP+= 1
          elif (UDP in pkt):
                   countUDP+= 1
```

hope I understood your question properly... let us know if it worked. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Its work but for the next time use [i] instead (i) and += for the counters.